# Why does CMP L and CMP M instructions in Microprocessor 8085 have same opcode BD?

Tags: cpu-registers, opcode, 8085, machine-instruction

**CMP L** compares Accumulator(A) contents with L register. **CMP M** compares Accumulator(A) contents with 8-bit data stored in the memory location as stored in H-L register pair. That's two different operations totally so why is there the same opcode **BD** for them both.

PS: Yeah I know that few Instructions have same opcode if they perform about the same task and have different names for referring to the same task. But what is it in this case?

Comment: Isn't `CMP M` 0xBE?

Comment: The operand field for `cmp m` is 110, the operand field for `cmp l` is 101